# Does Averaging the score from correlation across multiple variables yield a more accurate correlation score?

Tags: average, correlation

This may be a beginner question but I am making a application which I using to do correlation research to be used in financial markets.

The application pulls in different data sources and compares and allows the user to run various mathematical functions, but for now just correlation.

**My question is if I am comparing a multitude of data sources would my correlation score be more accurate if the scores were averaged?**

An example for my question would be:

I have Data Source A,B,C,D and I run correlation on AB,CD,AC,AD,BC,BD ----- if i averaged the correlated scores would they be more precise of a score?